# Are multiple MX/CNAME TXT records for the same domain ok?

Tags: dns, cname

We use Gmail for business and Amazon SES for sending email.

Just wondering if it ok in our CloudFlare DNS to have several `CNAME`, `TXT` and `MX` records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. There can not be a CNAME for the root(naked) domain, although some DNS providers detect that it is for the root domain and convert it to ALIAS (or some other type, in the back-end). Also a CNAME can not co-exist with other records for the same hostname (that is why there can not be for the root domain, it always has SOA and NS records and they can not be removed).

It is recommended to have more MX records for a given hostname for backup purposes, also there is no problem to have them for multiple hosts.

The TXT records also can be multiple for the same host, but not with the same values, for example there can not be 2 or more SPF records (SPF records are created as TXT RR, not as SPF RR (RR type 99)) for the same host.